# How to add fixed button to the bottom right of page

Tags: html, css, button, uibutton

I'm having some trouble adding a fixed button on the bottom of my webpage. Been testing out different numbers with the pixels, but the button hasn't been showing underneath the page on the right.

HTML

```
<a href="#head"><img src="upbutton.png" id="fixedbutton"></a>
```

CSS

```
.fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 560px;
    right: 1000px; 
}
```

Comment: You should be using `#fixedbutton` as a selector.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You are specifying `.fixedbutton` in your CSS (a class) and specifying the `id` on the element itself.

Change your CSS to the following, which will select the `id` fixedbutton

```
#fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWpkf) courtesy of [JoshC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680216/joshc).

Comment: I actually named it td#fixedbutton, so now it appeared. But the button is not aligned to where I want it to be.

Comment: Well, where do you want it?

Comment: Don't use a px postfix when you set it to zero.

Comment: this answer only for desktop devices, on mobile there is some issue. And i can't find any solution.

Comment: This makes the button overlap the scrollbar in chrome v.62

Answer (score 5):

This will be helpful for the **right bottom rounded button**

HTML :

```
      <a class="fixedButton" href>
         <div class="roundedFixedBtn"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
      </a>
```

CSS:

```
       .fixedButton{
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px; 
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .roundedFixedBtn{
          height: 60px;
          line-height: 80px;  
          width: 60px;  
          font-size: 2em;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Here is jsfiddle link   http://jsfiddle.net/vpthcsx8/11/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```css
.bottomFixButtionComponent{
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgb(27 27 24 / 75%);
  }
```

```html
      
       <h1> Bottom Fix component </h1>
      
        <div class="bottomFixButtionComponent"> 
          <button>Clear </button>
          <div>|</div>
          <button>Submit </button>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bottomFixButtionComponent{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgb(27 27 24 / 75%);
  }
```

```html
<h1> Bottom Fix component </h1>
      
        <div class="bottomFixButtionComponent"> 
          <button>Clear </button>
          <div>|</div>
          <button>Submit </button>
         </div>
```